# Class Diagram for a transport agency

Tags: php, uml, project

so i have to return a project for my school, the project is a web application for a transport agency, the problem is that i don't have a set of specifications for it, anyway this is some use cases if some would help me to come up with a class diagram:

- a client can:

  - create an account
  - Login
  - See the list of offers
  - Book offers
  - Proposing an offer with very specific criteria by sending a message ...
- The administrator can:

  - Login.
  - Manages information about customers, drivers and offers.
  - Get to Statistics (by date, vehicle, customer, driver ..).
  - Send and Receive messages from customers and drivers.
  - View Park (distribution of vehicles, Kilometers means, fuel consumption ..).
  - Manage the park (Adding, deleting, changing vehicles, drivers, clients) ...
- The driver can:

  - Login
  - Modify profile
  - View the key figures of its business: average mileage, list of vehicles driven ..
  - Obtain Notifications (next customer ..)
  - Send messages to the administrator.

this is what i did so far !!

[image]

i made some changes, this the new class diagram:

[image]

Comment: There is no point in someone giving you a class diagram for the above. Try one yourself then present it and ask for critique.

Comment: thanks for respond Thomas, i don't know how to post what i deed so far

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll take a look a bit later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your class diagram is ok in general. However, it lacks certain properties. To send an email (like required) you need the e-mail as property of the Client. The sane goes for statistics which eventually need a few more properties like Age/Sex of the driver (and what else). It continues with mileage (required below) for the car.

There are roles (I guess) Departure and Arrival. Those are represented with simple text without drawing box.

The (Vehicle/)Expense seems superfluous unless you use Expense somewhere else.

The drawing tool you used looks a bit (well) primitive. A bit layout to enhance readability would probably impress your teacher :-)

Comment: thanks a lot Thomas, i was just worried about the classes and the associations, the attributes and methods i'll add them later, and for the VehicleExpense i m trying to let the project open to changes if a new type of expense come up.

Comment: Yes. That looks much more pleasing. I did not check all the connectors in detail but from what I saw it looks ok.